# What set(s) is this piece from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, piece-information

[image]

What set is this from, or what is the piece number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is

[Part # 45301pb023 : Wedge 16 x 4 Triple Curved with SW V-wing Starfighter Pattern (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=45301pb023#T=C&C=11)

It appears in

[7915: Imperial V-wing Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/7915-1/Imperial-V-wing-Starfighter)
[image]

Comment: Also, although the part with sticker is found only on one set, the piece itself was used in a variety of colors in sets dating back to 2003.

Comment: I remember having that set. Unfortunately its in pieces and scattered across my collection now.